# Python trying to send request with requests library but nothing happened?

Tags: python, python-requests, header, timeout

Like the title said, im trying to send request a url using requests with headers, but when I try to print the status code it doesn't print anything in the terminal, I checked my internet connection and changed to test it but nothing changes.
Here's my code ;

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout
    link="https://www.exampleurl.com"
    header={
        "accept-language": "tr,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7",
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.1150.36'
    }
    r=requests.get(link)
    print(r.status_code)
```

When  I execute this command, nothing appears, don't know why. If someone can help me I will be so glad.

Comment: How do you know that any of the code is running? Can you add print statements to show which parts are working.

Comment: i tried to print before request.get code, it printed it but status code never printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same problem. The `get()` never returns.

Since you have created a `header` variable I thought about using that:

```py
r = requests.get(link, headers=header)
```

Now I get status `200` returned.

Comment: How i forgot the headers... Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

you can use request.head(link) like below:

```
r=requests.head(link)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Still same problem :/